# why does the string full of NULL after i got the name?

Tags: c, string

im a beginner and im trying to build a function that gets 2 pointer for 2 strings and copy the second string to the end of the first string (we can assume that there is enough place in the first string to containg both of them).
but the function actually only puts the 's' of 'stack' at the end of the first string, and between them there are a lot of 'NULL'. i dont really understand why.
can anyone help me understand the problem? thank you

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Strcat(char* t, char* s);

void main()
{
    char str1[14] = "zehavit", str2[] = "stack";
    Strcar(str1, str2);
    printf("%s", str1);
}

void Strcat(char * t, char * s)
{
    int i = 0, counter = 0;
    while ((*t) != '\0')
    {
        counter++;
        t++;
    }

    while ((*s) != '\0')
    {
        t[counter-1+i] = (*s);
        s++;
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to bung in a null character at the end!

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me you are doing lots of redundant stuff.
For example `t` has already been advanced, why are you adding also `counter` to it?
Maybe you could try something like this?

```
void Strcat(char * t, char * s)
{
    while (*t)
    {
        t++;
    }

    while (*s)
    {
        *t = *s;
        s++;
        t++;
    }

    *t=0;
}
```

Comment: And OP indeed forgot the terminating `0`. Well spotted.

Comment: @RadLexus Thank you for the comment.

Comment: thank you for your answer! it still doesnt work, i think that i have a problem with the main or the 2 string i choose.

Comment: @Giorgi Moniava now it works. i understood what was the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

After the first loop

```
int i = 0, counter = 0;
while ((*t) != '\0')
{
    counter++;
    t++;
}
```

both `t` and `counter` have been moved by a length of the string, so

```
t[counter-1+i] = (*s);
```

starts to copy not from the end of string but twice as that minus 1.
Most likely you thought about:

```
while(*s)
    *t++ = *s++;

*t = '\0'; /* do not forget to NULL terminate that thing */
```

Comment: Please use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

There are two serious bugs in the function

The first one is that there is used the expression for the index

```
t[counter-1+i] = (*s);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Let's assume for example that the first string is empty. In this case `counter` will be equal to 0.

So in the second loop of the function when `i` is also equal to 0 there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

```
while ((*s) != '\0')
{
    t[counter-1+i] = (*s); // if counter and i is equal to 0 then there is t[-1] 
    s++;
    i++;
}
```

The second bug is that the resulted string is not appended with the terminating zero.

Also it is preferable when the function returns pointer to the resulted string.

Thus the function can look like

```
char * Strcat(char *t, const char *s)
{
    char *p = t;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    do { *p++ = *s; } while ( *s++ );

    return t;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * Strcat(char *t, const char *s)
{
    char *p = t;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    do { *p++ = *s; } while ( *s++ );

    return t;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char t[12] = "Hello ";
    char *s = "World";

    puts( Strcat( t, s ) );
}
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your answers! it still doesnt work well... i think the problem is in the main because the function looks good... :/

Comment: @Jovani See my updated post. There was a typo in the function: a semicolon was missed.

Answer (score 0):

suggest changing this loop:

```
while ((*s) != '\0')
{
    t[counter-1+i] = (*s);
    s++;
    i++;
}
```

to:

```
// append all of second string, except NUL terminator byte
for( i=0; s[i]; i++ )
    t[counter+i] = s[i];

// append NUL terminator byte
t[counter+i] = '\0';
```